# How to remove decimal values from a value of type 'double' in Java

Tags: java

I am invoking a method called "calculateStampDuty", which will return the
amount of stamp duty to be paid on a property. The percentage calculation works
fine, and returns the correct value of "15000.0". However, I want to display the value to
the front end user as just "15000", so just want to remove the decimal and any preceding values
thereafter. How can this be done? My code is below:

```
float HouseValue = 150000;
double percentageValue;

percentageValue = calculateStampDuty(10, HouseValue);

private double calculateStampDuty(int PercentageIn, double HouseValueIn){
    double test = PercentageIn * HouseValueIn / 100;
    return test;
}
```

I have tried the following:

- Creating a new string which will convert the double value to a string, as per below:

  `String newValue = percentageValue.toString();`
- I have tried using the 'valueOf' method on the String object, as per below:

  `String total2 = String.valueOf(percentageValue);`

However, I just cannot get a value with no decimal places. Does anyone know
in this example how you would get "15000" instead of "15000.0"?

Thanks

Comment: You can use integer if you don't want decimals at all, if you just don't want decimal format when you have an integer then DecimalFormat should work.

Comment: Using a `float` for a currency value is your first problem. Use `BigDecimal` instead - binary floating point isn't suitable for "manmade" values like currency.

Comment: @JonSkeet Or just an `int` amount of cents.

Comment: @Doorknob: Potentially - but personally I'd rather use a type that meant I *didn't* have to remember that everywhere I used it. It depends on the context though, agreed.

Comment: int for cents works if you know you're only ever going to be dealing with whole cents, and not fractions of a cent.  Ever.

Comment: Should 15000.9 be converted to 15001 or 15000?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can convert the `double` value into a `int` value.
`int x = (int) y` where y is your double variable. Then, printing `x` does not give decimal places (`15000` instead of `15000.0`).

Comment: typecast to int is not advisable as your double may be beyond the range int supports

Comment: How is this the answer? I get a compilation error says that you cannot cast a double to an int.

Comment: @C-Otto I just did it in Java6 and Java7 double dbtest = 1.0; int inttest = (int)dbtest; inconvertible types. What am I doing wrong then?

Comment: Nevermind @C-Otto Doornob found that I was using Double instead of double. Thanks for correcting me though.

Comment: raghavsood33 casting to int is okay so long as you are willing to forgo your precision. However, don't do this if you work for NASA rocket systems.

Comment: @F.O.O it's not only about precision, but also about range. Compare the max values for double and int.

Comment: As @raghavsood33 said, direct typecasting to int is a bad idea

Comment: This may result in rounding

Comment: this is a poor answer as if the value of double is large then it can not be typecasted to an int correctly.

Answer (score 93):

Nice and simple. Add this snippet in whatever you're outputting to:

```
String.format("%.0f", percentageValue)
```

Comment: 4.6 -> 5, 3.4 -> 3 I think it rounds the number up, not remove the numbers after the period.

Comment: String.format is the slowest way to do this [according to here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-double-to-string).

Answer (score 52):

I did this to remove the decimal places from the `double` value

```
new DecimalFormat("#").format(100.0);
```

The output of the above is

> 100

Answer (score 16):

You could use

```
String newValue = Integer.toString((int)percentageValue);
```

Or

```
String newValue = Double.toString(Math.floor(percentageValue));
```

Comment: How do you call toString() on a primitive?

Comment: cannot cast a double to an int.

Comment: @Doorknob Yes, I just did it in Java6 and Java7 double dbtest = 1.0; int inttest = (int)dbtest; inconvertible types. What am I doing wrong then?

Comment: @AbuSulaiman Post your entire code here then (with http://pastebin.com for example), because something else is wrong and the cast is not the problem.

Comment: @AbuSulaiman You're using a `Double`, which is an object. You need to use the primitive, `double`, instead.

Comment: Oh! Man, I'm so stupid. I'm sorry, thanks for spending your time because I don't think I would have ever realized what was wrong.

Comment: @AbuSulaiman Haha, no problem. I've spent far longer on far more obvious bugs before. :)

Answer (score 10):

You can convert `double`,`float` variables to `integer` in a single line of code using **explicit type casting**.

```
float x = 3.05
int y = (int) x;
System.out.println(y);
```

The output will be `3`

Answer (score 5):

Try this you will get a string from the format method.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##0");

df.format((Math.round(doubleValue * 100.0) / 100.0));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Double d = 1000d;
System.out.println("Normal value :"+d);
System.out.println("Without decimal points :"+d.longValue());
```

Answer (score 4):

I would try this:

```
String numWihoutDecimal = String.valueOf(percentageValue).split("\\.")[0];
```

I've tested this and it works so then it's just convert from this string to whatever type of number or whatever variable you want. You could do something like this.

```
int num = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(percentageValue).split("\\.")[0]);
```

Comment: String.valueOf not advisable as your double can com out to be in exponential/scentific notation e.g., 9.99999E11

Answer (score 4):

Use
    Math.Round(double);

I have used it myself.  It actually rounds off the decimal places.

```
d = 19.82;
ans = Math.round(d);
System.out.println(ans);
// Output : 20 

d = 19.33;
ans = Math.round(d);
System.out.println(ans);
// Output : 19
```

Hope it Helps :-)

Answer (score 4):

the simple way to remove

```
new java.text.DecimalFormat("#").format(value)
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution is by using [**DecimalFormat class**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html). This class provides a lot of functionality to format a number.
To get a double value as string with no decimals use the code below.

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(".");
decimalFormat.setGroupingUsed(false);
decimalFormat.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(false);

String year = decimalFormat.format(32024.2345D);
```

Answer (score 1):

With a cast. You're basically telling the compiler "I know that I'll lose information with this, but it's okay". And then you convert the casted integer into a string to display it.

```
String newValue = ((int) percentageValue).toString();
```

Comment: typecast to int is not advisable as your double may be beyond the range int supports

Comment: toString() on primitive int not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DecimalFormat, but please also note that it is not a good idea to use double in these situations, rather use BigDecimal

Comment: DecimalFormat rounds and not truncates

Answer (score 1):

`String truncatedValue = String.format("%f", percentageValue).split("\\.")[0];` solves the purpose

The problem is two fold-

1. To retain the integral (mathematical integer) part of the double. Hence can't typecast `(int) percentageValue`
2. Truncate (and not round) the decimal part. Hence can't use `String.format("%.0f", percentageValue)` or `new java.text.DecimalFormat("#").format(percentageValue)` as both of these round the decimal part.

Answer (score 1):

Type casting to **integer** may create problem but even **long** type can not hold every bit of double after narrowing down to decimal places. If you know your values will never exceed **Long.MAX_VALUE** value, this might be a clean solution.

So use the following with the above known risk.

```
double mValue = 1234567890.123456;
long mStrippedValue = new Double(mValue).longValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use the method `int integerValue = (int)Math.round(double a);`

Answer (score 1):

```
Double i = Double.parseDouble("String with double value");

Log.i(tag, "display double " + i);

try {
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(0); // set as you need
    String myStringmax = nf.format(i);

    String result = myStringmax.replaceAll("[-+.^:,]", "");

    Double i = Double.parseDouble(result);

    int max = Integer.parseInt(result);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("ex=" + e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

declare a double value and convert to long convert to string and formated to float the double value finally replace all the value like 123456789,0000 to 123456789

```
Double value = double value ;
Long longValue = value.longValue();  
String strCellValue1 = new String(longValue.toString().format("%f",value).replaceAll("\\,?0*$", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
System.out.println(percentageValue.split("\\.")[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class RemoveDecimalPoint{

         public static void main(String []args){
            System.out.println(""+ removePoint(250022005.60));
         }
 
       public static String  removePoint(double number) {        
            long x = (long) number;
            return x+"";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't casting `number` to a long already remove the decimal portion of the number?

Comment: it required  to prevent a Round of value and get an actual number when used only  NumberFormat  then output is 250022006 but I jut remove .60  and need to  250022005

Comment: So yes... I am asking because the NumberFormat is not needed when the number has already been truncated.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
String newValue = String.format("%d", (int)d);
```

Comment: typecast to int is not advisable as your double may be beyond the range int supports