# How to remove decimal value from the Barchart?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, mpandroidchart

I want to remove decimal value from the BarChart in [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). Even though I have taken it as a Integer value while displaying it is showing decimal and adding up .0 for my value as.

ex: If my value is 65, it is displaying 75.0.(I want to remove that .0 part)

I m using the library called **"mpandroidchartlibrary-2-1-4"**

below is my code snippet in integer.

```
            Double a= Double.parseDouble(total_week);
            int b=a.intValue();

            Double a1= Double.parseDouble(complitiontest);
            int b1=a1.intValue();

            Log.d("duoosfsd","****  "+b1);

            entries.add(new BarEntry(b,0));
            entries.add(new BarEntry(b1,1));
```

Here the b1 is value which is Integer value even when I print in log it prints only as 75 but while showing it will show as 75.0.

Attached screenshot please check.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060406/how-to-remove-decimal-values-from-a-value-of-type-double-in-java

Answer (score 5):

```
public class MyValueFormatter implements ValueFormatter {

        private DecimalFormat mFormat;

        public MyValueFormatter() {
            mFormat = new DecimalFormat("#");
        }

        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
            return mFormat.format(value);
        }
    }
```

call this on  BarData class object

```
data.setValueFormatter(new MyValueFormatter());
```

Comment: Thank you BTW - compiler fixing `implements ValueFormatter` to `extends ValueFormatter`

Answer (score 0):

I did try for same and below worked for me.

new DecimalFormat("#").format(100.0);

Answer (score 0):

You first need to check the **mpandroidchartlibrary-2-1-4** library's code.

In that library find the method which is used to display the number on the bar.

As per my understanding, it converts integer into float or either it is displaying float value to the bar at the time of display.

**Advice :** Please check library code and understand it first. And if you find something and want to change it, then you have to import this project as library and then only you can do changes as per your requirement.