# How to remove digits after decimal in a double?

Tags: android, string, double

my `double = 42.12323532` I want it to show just `"42"`. How do I do that? This is what I have tried-

```
     TV_BMR.setText("BMR: " + String.format("%.2f", BMR) + " cal");
```

but this only rounds it to 2 digits. I want everything removed after the decimal. Including the decimal.

Comment: Possible duplication of [How to remove decimal values from a value of type 'double' in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060406/how-to-remove-decimal-values-from-a-value-of-type-double-in-java)

Comment: You could cast double into the int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String str = “BMR: “ + (int)BMR;
```

Comment: I owe you krispy kreme donuts Dimitri! unless you want vodka

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = “BMR: “ + (long)BMR;
```

Then we can, In the high double type range numbers everything removed after the decimal.