# How to remove the decimal part if it is only 0?

Tags: java

There is a calculation : `Double ret = Double.parseDouble(v.getCible_1()) - Double.parseDouble(v.getRealise_1());`

If `ret = 68.0` how to get only `ret = 68` ?

EDIT : I want to keep decimal part if it is not 0 , for example ret = 68.4 will be ok.

Comment: Are you talking about when you print it? If it's a double, it'll have to have a decimal portion. You can just choose to not print it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove decimal values from a value of type 'double' in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060406/how-to-remove-decimal-values-from-a-value-of-type-double-in-java)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can cast it to an `int` and compare it with the `double` value. If the comparison results in `true` then you have to use the converted value or else continue using the `double`.

Do something like this,

```
private String getResultValue(double ret) {
    int convertedValue = (int) ret;
    return String.valueOf(ret == convertedValue ? convertedValue : ret);
}
```

For Example,

- When `ret` = 68.0, `convertedValue` = 68 --> **Comparison:** `True`, 
  **Returned Value:** 68
- When `ret` = 68.4, `convertedValue` = 68 --> **Comparison:** `False`, **Returned Value:** 68.4

Comment: Note that does not work for numbers larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Using `ret % 1 == 0` for the check rectifies this. However, you cannot convert to `int` in that case anyway.

Comment: @lzruo I agree that it might not work for `INT MAX` but OP has not indicated if he can get a value greater than the INT bounds. Depending on the needs you can use a `long` or maybe modulo as you suggested. I was only trying to provide the answer of what is asked in the question. This is not a test where I'm being assessed and I should consider all the edge cases for the snippet to work properly.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly my intention. I only wanted to note about this corner case, nothing more. (I did not downvote)

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this.

```
double doubleValue = 68.1;
    int intValue = (int)doubleValue;

    double minus = doubleValue-intValue;
    if(minus != 0.0){
        System.out.println(doubleValue);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println(intValue);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DecimalFormat Class to format numbers.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Answer (score -1):

You can convert it to int .. like this

```
int value = (int) 68.0;
```

it will give you 68

Comment: but what if ret contains decimal non 0 ? it will throw exception !

Comment: then you can use this then `double ret = 68.0;
   DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.#");
  System.out.println(df.format(ret));`

Comment: @pheromix it certainly **will not** throw any exceptions